# How can I share data between controllers in an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I have an Angular app using UI Router with nested ui-view containers. Here, the left sidebar part of parent ui-view, and then the right content area is nested inside the parent ui-view:

[image: Screenshot]

*I'm looking for an elegant solution to sharing data between the parent and child views.* Here are some **considerations**:

1. I want to avoid data becoming stale within the cached Angular app;
2. $scope is allegedly going away with Angular 2.0 in favor of controllerAs.
3. I'd like a reusable pattern to minimize copy/paste code.

Here are some **solutions** I've thought of (and pointed out the downsides), but I'm not super happy with any:

1. ***Share data via controllerAs + $scope:***

   productController:

   ```
   var product = this;

   product.products = products.data;  // array injected via resolve
   ```

   productEditController:

   ```
   var productEdit = this;

   productEdit.product = product.data;  // object injected via resolve

   productEdit.save = function(product) {
       productService.save(product);

       // Update shared data.
       // DOWNSIDE: RELIES ON $scope TO UPDATE PARENT.
       var editedProduct = _.find($scope.product, function(item) {return item._id === product._id});
       $scope.product.products[$scope.product.products.indexof(editedProduct)] = editedProduct;
   };
   ```

   productEdit template:

   ```
   <form ng-submit="productEdit.save()">...</form>
   ```

   productService:

   ```
   productService.save = function(data) {
       return $http.put('http://my.api.com/products/' + data._id, data);
   };
   ```
2. ***Share data via shared resolve data:***

   productController:

   ```
   var product = this;

   product.products = products.data;  // array injected via resolve
   ```

   productEditController:

   ```
   var productEdit = this;

   productEdit.products = products.data;  // array injected via resolve, defined in productController resolve
   productEdit.product = product.data;  // object injected via resolve

   productEdit.save = function(product) {
       productService.save(product);

       // Update shared data.
       // DOWNSIDE: THIS IS COPY/PASTE AND NOT REUSABLE.
       var editedProduct = _.find(productEdit.products, function(item) {return item._id === product._id});
       productEdit.products[productEdit.products.indexof(editedProduct)] = editedProduct;
   };
   ```

   productEdit template:

   ```
   <form ng-submit="productEdit.save()">...</form>
   ```

   productService:

   ```
   productService.save = function(data) {
       return $http.put('http://my.api.com/products/' + data._id, data);
   };
   ```
3. ***Share data via a service:***

   routes:

   ```
   controller: productController
   resolve: {
       products: function(productsService) {
           return productsService.all();
       }
   }
   ```

   productController:

   ```
   var product = this;

   product.products = products.data;  // array injected via resolve
   ```

   productEditController:

   ```
   var productEdit = this;

   productEdit.product = product.data;  // object injected via resolve

   productEdit.save = function(product) {
       // SERVICE WILL TAKE CARE OF UPDATING SHARED DATA.
       productService.save(product);
   };
   ```

   productEdit template:

   ```
   <form ng-submit="productEdit.save()">...</form>
   ```

   productService:

   ```
   // Shared store/cache of product data, accessible across controllers.
   productService.products = null;

   productService.all = function() {
       // DOWNSIDE: THIS CAN RESULT IN CONTROLLERS GETTING STALE DATA.
       if (productService.products) {
           return productService.products;
       }

       var promise = $http.get('http://my.api.com/products');

       promise.success(function(data) {
           productService.products = data;
       });

       return promise;
   };

   productService.find = function(id) {
       var product;

       if (productService.products) {
           // DOWNSIDE: THIS CAN RESULT IN CONTROLLERS GETTING STALE DATA.
           product = productService.products;
       }

       if (!product) {
           product = $http.get('http://my.api.com/products/' + id);
       }

       return product;
   };

   productService.save = function(data) {
       var promise = $http.put('http://my.api.com/products/' + data._id, data);

       promise.success(function(data) {
           var editedProduct = _.find(productService.products, function(item) {return item._id === data._id});
           productService.products[productService.products.indexof(editedProduct)] = editedProduct;
       });

       return promise;
   };
   ```

I've also considered using a realtime service, but I don't have time to implement that now across the board.

Is there another, elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: what else approach is remaining? you have covered all.. I liked the service approach..

Comment: The need for `$scope` in alternative 1 looks like a design flaw to me. You also didn't consider events. After all the controllers don't need to actually share data. As I see it data just needs to stay in synch.

Comment: The last solution that comes to my mind (although it isn't best practise) is to share data on the `$rootScope` (but that won't be a solution with Angular 2.0 I guess). The best way IMHO is to share data with a service.

Comment: You covered all approaches , when you want to have synchronized snapshot of data across whole application, then after  productsService.all(); sotre it inside service. for example productService.backenData , then inject service in another controller, and on save call productService.save() and inside save again update productService.backendData, if you inject your service in any part of application you can be sure that you have fresh and synced data. That is best approach to avoid any un-sync data across appliaction. This is most elegant and best design pattern solution.

Comment: @MilosMosovsky What worries me with this approach is that since data is cached in productService.products when productService.all() is called, then subsequent calls to productService.all() will return productService.products which may not be current with the server.

Comment: Do you mean parallel calls at one time by one user?

Comment: They wont be de-synced , as you will be resolving promise with fresh data from backend , if user will double-call service.all() , the last request resolved will be binded to 'scope' , so ther is not possibility of de-syncing data with user. (I dont have any use-case currently in mind how to achieve de-syncing in this approach)

Comment: @MilosMosovsky Have a look at my implementation of productService.all(). If productService.products is set, then it (a cache) will always be returned. So, if another user using the web site changes one of the products, old/stale data will remain in the cache (productService.products) and will be returned with subsequent calls to productService.all().

Comment: And why you have this approach? I think productService.all() should always return backend data

Comment: That approach is the key to sharing a reference to an array across controllers in the third option.